# How do I make the falling down effect on my navigation bar slower?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I was writing a webpage for my personal website. I had an idea where I would make a falling-down animated effect to make it look cooler instead of keeping it fixed. I've used bootstrap for my navigation. Was having difficulty in making the falling down effect a bit slower. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pop-up Navbar Example</title>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS link here -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top-section">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark hidden-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="/docs/5.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24"
                        class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                    Bootstrap
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </nav>
    <script src="./function.js"></script>
</html >
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
/* Add this CSS to control the pop-up navbar and its appearance */
.hidden-navbar {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
}

.top-section {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top-section:hover + .hidden-navbar {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0; /* Slide the navbar down from the top */
    transform: translateY(0);
    animation: slideDown 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Apply the animation */
  }
@keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    100% {
      top: 0;
    }
  }
```

.js

```
// Add this JavaScript to handle the hover effect and pop-up functionality
document.querySelector('.top-section').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.display = 'block';
});

document.querySelector('.navbar').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Was experimenting with various CSS tags but couldn't really find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change speed here. Current is 0.2 seconds

```
animation: slideDown 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Apply the animation */
```